# Excel to Word wrong range copied if sheet containing range not active

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've found a weird quirk when copying a range from Excel to Word in Office 2016 (not tried in other versions) as an OLEObject. The VBA is in Excel. Here's the code, it locates a bookmark in the Word file, pastes in the table and resets the bookmark:

```
Set wordRange = wordDoc.bookmarks("Table").Range
wsService.Range("A1:B15").Copy
wordRange.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=0, Placement:=0
wordDoc.bookmarks.Add "Table", wordRange
```

This works if sheet `wsService` is active in Excel. If not `Range("A1:B15")` on the active sheet is copied instead. I've tried other data types (e.g. bitmap, metafile, shape) and they all work fine. Is this a bug?

Comment: How are you setting the object `wsService` ?

Comment: Its the sheets object name in properties. I'll try setting a variable instead and report back.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Nope, same problem

Comment: Have you tried `worksheets("sheetname").range("a1:b15")` ?

Comment: You could say that it is a bug, but you can solve with some tricks, like Application.ScreenUpdating = False & wsService.visible = false while is running the program and before ending 
activate your sheet again,  Application.ScreenUpdating = true and  wsService.visible = true. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yup

Comment: @AaronPanVega Thanks, yeah, I've fudged it in various ways, mostly just professional curiosity now

Answer (score 0):

Your description suggests all you're doing with wsService is pointing it to the ActiveSheet. For example:

```
set wsService = ActiveSheet
```

instead of saying which particular worksheet it should use:

```
set wsService = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

This way, the worksheet need not be visible to copy anything from it.

Comment: No, that's not the case, please see the comments above

Comment: @Absinthe Regardless of your "comments above", it simply isn't necessary to activate a sheet before copying & pasting it into Word. The *real* problem here concerns a bug with the PasteSpecial - if you set Link:=True, you'll get the correct sheet. You can then unlink the pasted object.

Comment: Additionally, when you paste with Link:=False and DataType:=0, you get the *entire* workbook. But if the sheet you want isn't active, you'll get the active sheet displayed or, if the workbook isn't active, the first sheet displayed. So, you are getting the correct data; it's just not visible. You could activate the object after pasting and switch sheets.